# ListView_DeleteItem loop only deletes half the items it should

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, activex

I have a list view inside an activex control that contains approximately 700 items. When a filter event occurs, items are removed from the list view using the code below, leaving only a few filtered items. I have noticed that the first 300 of 700 items are deleted successfully, however the rest then fail to delete (ListView_DeleteItem returns false). On subsequent calls to the code, half of the remaining items that should be removed are deleted, and then half again etc. Eventually all of the items that should be deleted have been, however it takes probably 5 or six calls to the loop below.

```
    for (size_t rowNum=0; rowNum < toDelete.size() ; rowNum ++)
{
    bool result = ListView_DeleteItem(listCtrl, rowNum);
}
```

Comment: Loop in reverse so the ordinal index is not relating to a previously deleted item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
for (size_t rowNum=0; rowNum < toDelete.size() ; rowNum ++)
{
    bool result = ListView_DeleteItem(listCtrl, 0);
}
```

This is what happens with your code :

Initial list :

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
```

First pass of the loop: you remove item with index 0 (Item 1), the list becomes this:

```
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
```

Second pass of the loop: you remove item with index 1 (which is now Item 3), the list becomes this:

```
Item 2
Item 4
```

and so on.

Comment: That's fixed the issue thanks.
Explains why ListView_DeleteItem was returning 0, the index must have been way above the actual length of the list